# getting error when i write java program in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I installed eclipse in my system when i wrote some sample hello world program in that its throwing me error like launching hello world has encountered problem.
The specified JRE does not exist.

Any1 help me on this

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your settings in "Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs"?

Also you could try to (re)install [Java SE (JDK)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)